# Sitecore: reference item in other database ( source field )

Tags: c#, sitecore

I'm using Sitecore 8 Update 2.
I've added extra fields to the user profile and have some static items that i would like to use to fill up droplist fields.

The template for the user profiles however is in the core database and the items i want to use to fill up the droplist fields are located in the master/web database.

Is there a way to the items to the source field ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define "database" in your field. Like so:

```
databasename=web&datasource=/sitecore/content/Meta Content/Lookup Lists/Countries
```

See also: https://sitecorecontextitem.wordpress.com/2014/02/10/working-with-custom-user-profile-fields-in-sitecore/